# CGVectorMake to move SKNode at a certain speed towards the middle of screen?

Tags: physics, ios, linear-algebra, spritekit

I am trying to launch my ball sprite towards the middle of the screen at the same speed every time I launch it.

```
let vel: CGFloat = 1000

dx = size.width / 2 - ball.position.x
dy = vel - size.height / 2 - ball.position.y

ball.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(dx, dy)
```

This works in that it does launch the ball towards the center of the screen but at differing speeds depending on where the ball starts from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was misunderstanding the way vectors in SpriteKit are represented. The solution I used was:

```
dx = (size.width / 2 - ball.position.x) * vel
dy = (size.height / 2 - ball.position.y) * vel
```